# Limiting new line in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am trying to limit the lines in the textarea. The maximum lines I want are 6 lines only. So far everything is fine.

If I put something like this in the textarea:

1. d
2. d
3. d
4. d(Press enter here)
5. d
6. Long text here.....................

Once you press enter in line 4, it becomes like this

1. d
2. d
3. d
4. d
5. 
6. d

It erases the last line which can be a problem if the user has put some long text at the end of the sentence.

I've been trying to find a way to limit the lines to 6 only, it should handle also the paste event.

Here is my code:

```
<textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('textarea').bind('change keyup', function(event) {
  rows = 6;
  var value = '';
  var splitval = $(this).val().split("\n");

  for(var a=0;a<rows && typeof splitval[a] != 'undefined';a++) {
    if(a>0) value += "\n";
    value += splitval[a];
  }
  $(this).val(value);
});

</script>
```

Comment: What if they just type one really long line that wraps onto 6+ lines?

Comment: I have maxlength set to 700. I am just worrying if a user decided to create more than 6 lines.

Comment: So make an error when it is more than 6 and do not remove it.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent them from creating more lines once it reaches 6 lines? How can I do this also in paste event especially if they are pasting something that has more than 6 lines?

Comment: Typically you would have a much better user-experience if you let them type whatever they want, and just highlight when it fails your validation. For an example of this, see Twitter. It lets you type the history of the world, but most of it will be highlighted in red as being too long.

Comment: Yes, but my textarea has an image background, if I allow them to use more lines, it will ruin the layout